# Validate parameter of constructor before calling superclass constructor

Tags: java, constructor

For example, constructor like this :

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
     public Car(Car a){
         super(a.getName()); //what if 'a' is null 
     }
}
```

I cannot check condition of parameter before calling super().

Comment: you would get an NPE, do check for it in such case

Comment: This is a copy constructor, check a before calling it.

Comment: `super(Objects.requireNonNull(a, "message").getName());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend to use a factory method in this case:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private Car(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public static Car of(Car a) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(a, "a is required");
        return new Car(a.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do simple

```
super(a != null ? a.getName() : resolveNullA())
```

but the better solution would be to create the `Car` instance by using some implementation of [Factory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

```
public class VehicleFactory {
    ...

    public Car getCar(Car anotherCar) {
        if(anotherCar != null) {
            return new Car(anotherCar.getName()); 
        } else {
            resolveNullAnotherCar();
        }
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the responsibility of checking for `null` to the super class instead.

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car (Car a) {
        super(a);
    }
}

public class Vehicle {
    public Vehicle (Vehicle v) {
        if(v != null) {
            this.name = v.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the issue, it is calling a.getName() if a is null

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for a builder method as [Illya Kysil](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1091731) suggests, however, you could also delegate the null checking to a static method.

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private Car(Car car) {
        super(getName(car));
    }

    private static String getName(Car car) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(car, "Input car must be non null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(car.getName(), "Input car name must be non null");
        return car.getName();
    }
}
```

The main restriction is that the `super` call must be made as the first statement. As long as the expressions combine to create the `super` constructor statement, it's possible to run any arbitrary set of code *(except in the case of a zero param ctor)*.

It might also be just as easy to validate the parameters after `super` is called. This might not be a great solution if the base constructor takes a long time to execute and you'd rather the code fail fast

```
private Car(Car car) {
    super(getName(car));
    Objects.requireNonNull(car.getName(), "Input car name must be non null");
}
```